# How can I change the SSL version in `aiohttp` request?

Tags: python, python-requests, aiohttp

As suggested to solve the problem in `requests`

```py
Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:645)SSLErrorEOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

I can do something as :

```py
class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False, **pool_kwargs):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections,
            maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block,
            ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
        )
# then 
import requests
s=requests.session()
s.mount("https://", MyAdapter)
```

How can I do the same thing with `aiohttp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ssl_context* is the field that you can use. Check this out:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext